# Why am I asked to run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-4

On Rails 4.0.0.rc1, Ruby 2.0.0, after I run a migration, I see the following error when I try to run a test through `rspec`:

> /Users/peeja/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:376:in
>   `check_pending!': Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate
>   RAILS_ENV=test' to resolve this issue.
>   (ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError)

That doesn't seem right. No one migrates their test database, do they? They `db:test:prepare` it, which—to be fair—I've forgotten to do. So I run `rake db:test:prepare` and run my `rspec` command again…and see the same error.

If I actually `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`, the error does in fact go away.

What's going on? Is this new in Rails 4?

Comment: Does `rake db:test:prepare` works?

Comment: For me `rake db:test:prepare` does not work even if `schema.rb` is up to date. Only migrating the test database works.

Comment: Checkout my answer here, hope it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33054787/4902373

Comment: `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` solved it for me.

Comment: I fixed this by adding `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` just before `RSpec.configure` block in `rails_helper.rb`

Docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#pending-migration-checks

Comment: On a side note, but... what's wrong with migrating a test database?..

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As of Rails 4.1, the `rake db:test:*` tasks are deprecated. Instead, your `(test|spec)_helper.rb` should include:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

This means that your test database will get the correct schema every time your tests run, whether you run them from a Rake task or not.

Comment: Thanks for that one, I've actually missed that one when 4.1 got released I guess.

Comment: This is correct and is the best way to me to keep up to date your test database. The error being that _you have pending migrations to run_. But if anyone don't want to follow this great workaround, I suggest you delete the Test Database and run afresh `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test` to re-create your test database, and the run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` just to migrate the test database. I do this often when am yet to write tests for my application.

Comment: I can see this line in `tests_helper.rb` in rails 5 out of box

Comment: Be careful with this. If you have multiple test database connections and do not have migration files for all them, ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema! will not load the development schema into the into the test schema for those connections and you will still have to load it manually.

Comment: BTW I couldn't get this to work with `Test::Unit` (e.g. in `test/test_helper.rb`)

Answer (score 31):

Looks like `rake test:prepare` works, not sure what `db:test:prepare` now does.

Comment: Wow. Hit it on the head. Thanks! https://gist.github.com/Peeja/5831155 Now to file a Rails bug…

Comment: Huh. When I first posted that I missed that `test:prepare` *is* calling (depending on) `db:test:prepare`. All the good stuff seems to happen outside of `db:test:prepare`, though. Here's the Rails code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/067e1505d4e054df566e065f4faf11ee4b430a3d/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L399

Comment: It looks like the database is created from 'schema.rb' in `db:test:load` which `test:prepare` calls after `db:test:prepare`. But it also looks like `db:test:load` is invoked directly from from `db:test:prepare`.

Comment: I see that in the code, but I'm pretty sure that a (successful) `Rake::Task#invoke` shows up in the `rake --trace` output, and I don't see it actually happening. Curious.

Answer (score 24):

You can also try

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

which works as

```
db:test:prepare
```

does:)

Comment: It doesn't, actually. `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` will migrate the test database. `rake db:test:prepare` will (would) load the schema into the test database, which is faster and less error-prone.

Answer (score 11):

I still have trouble sometimes in sorting this problem out when I just follow one person's answer so I have thrown a couple together to get better results. Here are the steps I take, not sure which ones are unnecessary, but it works in the end.

1. add `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` to the top of the test_helper.rb file.
2. `rake test:prepare`
3. `rake db:migrate`
4. `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Then when I run `bundle exec rake test` I get clean results every time with no pending migrations. (This is what I do right after generating the scaffold the first time). Someone feel free to correct me if you know for sure that one of these steps is absolutely not necessary, but this is how I make sure it works every time.

Answer (score 3):

I've found I have this problem when using `chruby` to manage my ruby versions. Rails calls `bin/rails db:test:prepare` via the system command. This doesn't take advantage of chrubys `$PATH` env var, so it runs as whatever the system ruby is, and fails because of missing gems typically. Unfortunately, I don't currently have a good solution for this.

Comment: Wow, how did you find it out? I'm also using `chruby` and `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` simply doesn't work for me. How did you debug it? Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide an answer for your case given the information you provided.

In my case it failed to "maintain the schema" (`spec/rails_helper.rb`, `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!`). Because I used the `postgres` database (running in a docker container). In this case there are 2 solutions:

- switch to a separate database (something other than `postgres`)
- use `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

To give you some more details, what `maintain_test_schema!` does is [it](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.8.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L599) runs [`bin/rails db:test:prepare`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.8.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L589) if there are pending migrations.

- `db:test:prepare` == [`db:test:load`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.8.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L345).
- before loading the schema `db:test:load` does [`db:test:purge`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.8.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L310).
- `db:test:purge` [disconnects](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.8.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L46-L48) from the db, drops and creates the db.
- before dropping the database it [establishes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.8.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L33) a [master connection](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.8.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L101-L106) (a connection under the `postgres` user)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set variable BEFORE command, like this.
This statement solved my problem:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is: why do we need to run this migration, not how to fix the error.

Comment: the order of that environment modified makes absolutely no difference