# Getting: "Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue." after cloning and migrating the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dbmigrate

I cloned my project. Bundled with "bundle install", then run "rake db:migrate". I am getting this error: (when I run the rails server and open my browser to localhost:3000) "Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue."

I checked all migrations one by one and all were executed without errors. Also no errors were shown after the execution of "rake db:migrate".

This is what I see when I execute "[rake db:migrate:status](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s238/sh/c6b9371c-2fd0-41b8-9d3d-038c2676bb31/a98ae6e0fd5ca6a769eefe2a270f348d)"

I am on development environment. Please let me know if you need any other information.

I also tried "bundle exec rake db:migrate", and "bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset" as "burninggramma" suggested.

Any clues what causes the error?

Comment: Please show us the output of ```rake db:migrate:status```. Are all migration scripts migrated?

Comment: You write in the first section: `, then run "rake db:migrate". I am getting this error: `. But you wrote also: `Also no errors were shown after the execution of "rake db:migrate".` So when did those errors come?

Comment: @burninggramma oh sorry. When i run the server and open localhost:3000 on my browser

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Interesting. Did you run *rake db:create*? Assuming you are using sqlite3, do this:

```
      rm -f db/*.sqlite3
      rake db:create
      RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate
      rails s -e development
```

Also, can you list the contents of your **config/database.yml** file?

Edit: **Warning!** Obviously, you will lose your existing data.

Comment: ok, its odd. now it works fine. I think db:create was the key but no clue why this was happening...

Comment: @stefanos-ioannou rake db:create creates the databases if it does not exist. Running migrate without creating the db should throw an error. Not sure what happened here. In retrospect, I would have probably tried rake db:migrate VERSION=0; rake db:migrate to see if there were any errors.

Answer (score 17):

After running the migrate command, I still had the same error.

What worked for me was to just stop the rails server and start it again.

Comment: Worked for me also

Comment: Same with me. I forgot I added `gem 'mysql2'` to my Gemfile which makes sense a restart would fix it.

Answer (score 6):

List your executed migrations with `rake db:migrate:status` and look if every migration was executed. You can try to cancel your migration with `rake db:abort_if_pending_migrations` and try to migrate again.

Comment: Check out the status here: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s238/sh/c6b9371c-2fd0-41b8-9d3d-038c2676bb31/a98ae6e0fd5ca6a769eefe2a270f348d

Comment: I also used the abort_if_pending and raked again (after dropping everyhting). Still nothing. No error was shown

Answer (score 4):

`1.` Maybe its default in ruby2/rails4 but have you tried: `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

`2.` Another option would be resetting the whole database - **use with CAUTION! resets all the data as well** - `bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset`

`+)` I would just make sure that you are executing everything in the same development env:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s
```

Comment: `bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset` works for me, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Running `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` did it for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in the  browser, but upon closely looking at the error message, I noticed some how I had an extra white space in the migrate comment and post files. Once I removed it, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Open the database and click schema_migration table. The migrations will be listed as below.
[image]

Sort the version column and find the latest migration you want to go back. Delete or Insert a new one. Rails keeps all the migration history in this table, so you can adjust the migration history to you liking.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error working on the *Learn Enough to Be Dangerous* Rails tutorial. I'm using Git Bash terminals on a Windows 10 machine. The error showed up in the terminal where I'm running guard, after I tried to migrate my db using the command (in another terminal):

`$ bundle exec rake db: migrate:`

After trying the solution offered by @lewstherin, I still got the same error. I tried the command:

`$ rails test`

And got the explicit and helpful warning:

`Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:`

```
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

I ran the command:

`$ bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

and now I'm working again.

Answer (score 1):

For me i just had to migrate for the error:

```
rake db:migrate --trace
```

By setting `false` to `config.active_record.migration_error` in `development.rb` might make it workable but i wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:
    -gem install rails -v 4.1.0
Inside Gemfile:
    -gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
(replace the newer/older with this)
Do bundle install and update
   -bundle install 
   -bundle update
In your application.rb :
Remove/Comment -  config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

run bundle rake:
   -bundle exec rake db:migrate
Refresh your page and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons 'db:migrate:reset' did not work for me

```
1) loosing data 
2) we moved from php to rails, so we had an existing DB and the migrations were written on top of it not from the scratch
```

So What I tried is to update the 'scheema_migrations'(mysql) table with the list of migrations(just version values) that I was really sure were already run on my db(development), this can be lil time consuming process but it works. I would not attempt this on production though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ***guessing*** the error is that you are creating a table that already exists, I had this problem before.
**Step 1** 
look into the error when you rake dv:migrate

**Step 2**
go to the model where this table is created

**Step 3**
add drop_table :[YOUR TABLE] right before the create_table :[YOUR TABLE]

**Step 2**
run rake db:migrate

**Step 3**
remove the drop_table once the your migration is done

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in genieacs and this code helped:

```
rake db:drop rake db:create rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=development
rake db:migrate rails s -e development
```

Answer (score -2):

You can always run rake db:reset

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11199924)

Comment: @RyanGates How does this not attempt to provide an answer? It might be completely wrong, [but that doesn't mean we should delete it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664) Please pay attention when reviewing.

Comment: @Undo This answer struck me as more of a comment because it sounded like a "try this" kind of comment. I do see what you mean about this being a genuine answer, and thank you for linking me to that post.