# Ruby Rails: ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When trying to deploy my Rails app to Railway I'm getting the following error:

**ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError**

```
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
You have 1 pending migration:
20221102234102_create_contacts.rb
```

I'm able to get the app online by clicking a button that appears below the message, which says "Run Pending Migration". I would like to Find a method to auto run that migration every deploy.

I've tried everything listed in [Getting: "Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue." after cloning and migrating the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309901/getting-migrations-are-pending-run-bin-rake-dbmigrate-rails-env-development)

So I've run:

```
      rm -f db/*.sqlite3
      rake db:create
      RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate
      rails s -e development
```

to no success.

The contents of the "20221102234102_create_contacts.rb" file are as follows:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :comments
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm completely new to web development and was following a free bootcamps videos to get this far, but they are using Heroku and that was unsuccessful, and since Heroku will no longer be free I figured I should try Railway out instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO and good job formatting your question!

Comment: Does `rm -f db/*.sqlite3` really delete the db? Try `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` (the three steps as a rake task)

Answer (score 0):

Railway will use a `Procfile` to start your service, so an easy way to make sure your migrations are run is to use this.

In the root folder of your app, add a file called `Procfile` (no extension)

Here's a sample from one of my apps:

```
web: /bin/bash -l -c "rake db:migrate && bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb"
```

This first runs `rake db:migrate` then it starts a `puma` server using the configurations I've defined in `config/puma.rb`

This command runs once after a successful build.