# Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development error when running as server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried to run as a server before and it worked well, I don't change anything in the database but when I tried to run again a have this message `Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

i tried as this site [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082002/migrations-are-pending-run-bin-rake-dbmigrate-rails-env-development-to-resol?rq=1#_=_)
but it failed 
any help please 
i am a beginner in ruby on rails

Comment: What happens when you run the command? (bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development)

Comment: rake aborted! ActiveRecord::DuplicatedMigrationNameError: Multiple migrations have the name create comments

Comment: @miro, well, rename your duplicate migration! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration files live in the `db/migrate` directory, and their names look like this:

```
20150121164407_create_comments.rb
```

From your comment, it looks like inside your `db/migrate` directory, you have several migrations with the same “basic” name `create_comments` (and probably different timestamps).
You need to remove one of those duplicated files.

Comment: thanks a lot i have found two files with the same name

Answer (score 0):

If you did and if you don't have any important data in the database, you should destroy your database and recreate it using existing migrations. These commands in this order:
`$ rake db:drop`
if you're using postgres
`$ rake db:create`
and finally remigrate
`$ rake db:migrate`

Comment: haven't seen comments while was writing answer. so that was just duplicated names