# In test environment, repeatedly keeps asking to run migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, minitest

On Rails - 5.0.3 and Ruby - 2.3.3, when I run `rails test`, it keeps asking me to run migrations. It does not maintain migrations state.

Tried following -

Adding `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` in test_helper.rb
    as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150529/why-am-i-asked-to-run-rake-dbmigrate-rails-env-test).

Can someone please help? Its really annoying and slow to run migrations everytime I run test.

[image]

**UPDATE**
After debugging a lot. Figured that rails/test_help is creating the issue.
If I comment it out, it works fine. Why is it that creating issue?

[image]

Comment: Does your `schema_migrations` tables has any records?

Comment: @Tai It inserts when I run migrations but after few minutes the whole DB becomes empty. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Do you use `database_cleaner` to clean up database after test? If so, can you pass your config?

Comment: No. Not using `database_cleaner`

Comment: How do you cleanup database after run test?

Comment: I just started working on a legacy code which din't have any tests. Only test_helper config file. No config for database cleanup but still cleans everytime. Hence confused