# Missing column on table when testing seed data with sqlite3 and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite3-ruby

I set up the Many to Many a couple days ago and came back to the part where we add seed data to test. I added this:

```
superman = Hero.find_or_create_by(name: 'Superman')
drmanhattan = Hero.find_or_create_by(name: 'Dr. Manhattan')
Team.find_or_create_by(name: "The Watchmen", hero: drmanhattan)
Team.find_or_create_by(name: "Doomnday Clock", hero: drmanhattan)
drmanhattan.teams.find_or_create_by(name:"Team 1")
drmanhattan.teams.find_or_create_by(name:"Team 2")
drmanhattan.teams.find_or_create_by(name:"Team 3")
```

here’s the error I get:

```
Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: heros.name
/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sqlite3-
```

whats strange is I see

`:name` - 
in the schema for heros

`t.string :name`
  - in the create_heros.rb file.
Since everything seems to be here..I'm not clear on what is happening.

Here is my repo  https://github.com/planetlucid/Ruby_On_Rails_Project

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150529/why-am-i-asked-to-run-rake-dbmigrate-rails-env-test

Comment: Whats the point of a team if can only take one hero? That is not a many to many association.